# Large $x$ power series for $e^{-\alpha x}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, asymptotics, power-series

Let $\alpha>0$, then do there exist continuous functions $c_n\colon\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R$ and $\gamma\colon\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\gamma\left(x\right)=0$ and the following equation is true for all $\alpha,x>0$
$$
e^{-\alpha x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n\left(\alpha\right)\gamma\left(x\right)^n
$$
If yes, how regular can we make $\gamma$, can it be smooth? Analytic? What about the $c_n$?

**Clarifying edit:** all the $x$-dependence is in $\gamma$ and all the $\alpha$ dependence is in the $c_n$

Comment: $c_1 (\alpha ) = 1,\quad c_2 (\alpha ) = c_3 (\alpha ) =  \ldots  = 0,\quad \gamma (x) = e^{ - \alpha x} $

Comment: $\gamma$ should be independent of $\alpha$, it is only a function of $x$. I have clarified in the question accordingly